# Teams remove the More Actions menu Item when posting an Adaptive Card to Channel

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm creating an escalation bot through the Bot Framework, using messaging extensions, when a users posts an issue(adaptive card) to the channel, a 'More Options' menu item appears when clicking on the eclipse of the post, this then allows users to make another issue on the same post. Is there a way to disable 'More Actions' so it is not shown/ or failing that disabled?

[image: Image of problem]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear - do you NEED the "Actions" menu command at all? If not, just remove that option from your message extension.  It can go into the "compose" box (when you create a new post), the "commandBox" (the main bar at the TOP of Teams) or "message" (this action menu you're talking about). From your other question today, it's clear you want it in "compose" box, but maybe you don't need it in the "message" action's menu. If that's correct, just de-select it in App Studio (i.e. in your manifest.json file).

If you -do- need it in the Actions box, you can't selectively turn it on/off, but you can choose how you respond when the user clicks that action. You could simply reply to the user that they've chosen an invalid option.

Comment: @alexcurtis, was this helpful to you at all?